# I want to dynamically set some objects' properties using a string in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to do something fairly straightforward in Visual Basic.

I want to be able to specify the following object properties

```
coltitle1.visible= false

coltitle2.visible= false

coltitle3.visible= false

coltitle4.visible= false

coltitle5.visible= false

coltitle6.visible= false

coltitle7.visible= false

coltitle8.visible= false
coltitle9.visible= false
coltitle10.visible= false
```

I want to use a for next loop like this...

```
   Dim f
  Dim output As String = ""
    For f = 1 To 10
       output = String.Concat("coltitle", f)
      output.visible = False
    Next
```

However, I know the (output.visible = False) line is wrong. How can I use the string I created to set the object's property?

Any help would be warmly appreciated. And aologies for bad coding :)

Cheers,
Luke

Answer (score 0):

What you have done in your code is just create a load of strings and then name them as a similar fashion.  What you need to do is loop through the objects (everything is an object) and then set the property.  In your case you would need to loop through the objects and then set each one's visible property to False.

As Im at work I don't have time to write some sample code but the links below should help you work it out.

Hope your doing ok

Mike

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/iterating-through-all-controls-on-the-form-with-vbnet/6157618

http://justinberke.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/loop-through-controls-in-vb.html